# EXCEL Multiple Continuous Ranges - need continuous answers for each range

Tags: excel-formula

I have spent a few hours working out how to do this which is why I'm posting it here now. I wanted that, for every 500 BDT it will charge 10 BDT. I wrote it with If formula.

For example:

IF J22 is ABOVE "0" BUT BELOW AND EQUAL "500" THEN display "10"
IF J22 is ABOVE "501" BUT BELOW AND EQUAL "1000" THEN display "20"
IF J22 is ABOVE "1001" BUT BELOW AND EQUAL "1500" THEN display "30"
IF J22 is ABOVE "1501" BUT BELOW AND EQUAL "2000" THEN display "40"

`=IF(J22<500,10,IF(J22<1000,20,IF(J22<1500,30,IF(J22<2000,40,IF(J22<2500,50,IF(J22<3000,60,IF(J22<3500,70,IF(J22<4000,80,IF(J22<4500,90,IF(J22<5000,100,IF(J22<5500,110,IF(J22<6000,120,IF(J22<6500,130,)))))))))))))`

I wrote it for 13 times again and again. And after that, I got angry if the amount is 22500BDT then I have to write the same thing for 225 times. Is there any shortcut formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of the function says `IF J22 is ABOVE "0" BUT BELOW AND EQUAL"500"` but the function you wrote says `=IF(J22<500`, so that's a bit of a quandary, but in general it looks like you're trying to add 10 to the result for every 500 or fraction thereof in your value. To do that you'd use something like

```
=(FLOOR(J22/500, 1)*10)+10
```

which is correct for the `IF(J22<500` case. If you *really* wanted `BELOW OR EQUAL "500"` then use

```
=(FLOOR((J22-1)/500, 1)*10)+10
```

Answer (score 0):

Presume the number you want to evaluate is in Cell `J22`, the following formula will work in the case of **LESS THAN AND EQUAL TO 500**

```
=ROUNDUP(J22/500,0)*10
```

and the following formula will work in the case of **LESS THAN 500**

```
=(ROUNDDOWN(J22/500,0)+1)*10
```